# Robolectric: Component using LocationManager throws NPE

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, robolectric, locationmanager

I'm using Robolectric to test a Service that gets a reference to the LocationManager in its onCreate() method, and requests a location update right after:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Other code...

    lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);

    // Other code...
}
```

The problem is, `NullPointerException` is thrown at `requestSingleUpdate()`. My test is annotated like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, emulateSdk = 19,
    manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
```

Notice that this occurs even outside the Service, in a simple unit test like this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Application app = RuntimeEnvironment.application;
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) app.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestSingleUpdate(...);
}
```

Where is the problem? Is there another way to test component that use system services like LocationManager?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to mock it by ShadowLocationManager.

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit? I don't get how a ShadowLocationManager could replace a LocationManager in my Service. Also, ShadowLocationManager doesn't even have requestSingleUpdate().

Comment: @Phil I assume that you don't want to unit test the location manager, you just want to unit test your code along the use of the location manager. By this way, this is better to mock the location manager with ShadowLocationManager and use simulateLocation( ) to get only one location update.

Comment: I still don't get how I can force my service to use and register to the mocked LocationManager instead of the one provided by the system. The service accepts no parameters and even if it did, ShadowLocationManager does not subclass LocationManager, so it cannot replace it.